# induced bi-regular subgraph of a bi-regular bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm not very familiar with the classical theorems and results that are well known to experts in graph theory, hope you don't mind if my question is too naive.

Given bi-regular bipartite graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V=V_1 \bigcup V_2$ and $V_1 \bigcap V_2=\emptyset$. Suppose $\text{deg}(u)=m, \forall u\in V_1$ and $\text{deg}(v)=n, \forall v\in V_2$. It then holds that $m|V_1|=n|V_2|$.

The question is: suppose there exists an integer $k < m$ such that $k|V_1|=n L$ where $L < |V_2|$ is an integer, can we always find an induced bi-regular subgraph by carefully choosing $L$ vertices in $|V_2|$ and all vertices in $V_1$?

The above condition is actually the sufficient condition if there exists a bi-regular graph, with $k$ and $n$ being the degrees of vertices.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to deal with this problem in terms of covers of $V_1$. Namely, for each vertex $v_2\in V_2$  a set $N(v_2)$ of its neighbors is a subset of $V_1$ of size $n$. Each vertex $v_1\in V_1$ is covered by a family $\mathcal U=\{N(v):v_2\in V_2\}$ exactly $m$ times. Given $k<m$ such that $kn$ is divisible by $r=|V_1|$ we want to find a subfamily $\mathcal V$ of a given $n$-uniform cover $\mathcal U$, which covers each vertex of $V_1$ exactly $k$ times. This is not always possible. For instance, recently [Andriy Yurchyshyn](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Mechanics/employees/e_Yurchishin.html), solving an other problem, for $r\in\{6,10,14,18\}$ constructed a family $\mathcal U$ of  subsets of a set $[r]=\{1,\dots,r\}$ of size $n=r/2$ each, such that each element $v_1\in [r]$ is covered exactly $m=\tfrac 14 {r \choose r/2}$ times and  $\mathcal U$ contains no subfamily $\mathcal V$ which covers each element $v_1\in [r]$ exactly $k=1$ times. The family $\mathcal U$ for $r=6$ is

> 124 235 346 451 562 613  123 345 561  246

The following subfamilies of $\mathcal U$ also produce  counterexamples:

> 124 235 346 451 562 613

and

> 123 345 561 246

Comment: Thanks! I've revised the question and stated it in a clearer way. The graph in this example is excluded from the considered problem. I appreciate it if you have a chance to take a look at the revised question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again for your impressive example. You're right that it is not necessarily true for any given graph. But what if the family $\mathcal{U}$ contains 'all' subsets of $[r]$ of equal size $n$?

Comment: @JZhao I guess the answer is positive, but it is hard for me to provide a respective subfamily $\mathcal V$ for any given $k$ because in general it should contain a lot of sets and I don’t see a general pattern for it. On the other can, we can build such a family for the smallest possible $k$ such that $kr=nL$ as follows. Place the elements of $[r]$ clockwise along a circle. Now start form $1$ and go clockwise along the circle, gathering the elements which we go along into sets of size $n$, till the last gathered set will end exactly before $1$.

Comment: For instance, for $r=5$ and $n=3$ we gather the sets: 123 451 234 512 345.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again for your comments. Yes I think what you mentioned should work. Equivalently we could solve a transportation problem and obtain the result. I’m wondering if we could find all the valid disjoint subfamilies given the whole family as the collection of all subsets of [r]. I guess this is positive but it’s hard to prove.